# How to iterate on concurrentLinkedQueue by multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In my application data producing speed (which is stored in in concurrentLinkedQueue) is greater than i can consume with single thread.

I have decided to start with creating 4 threads to consume the data, to prevent my application from "out of memory exception".

Questions :

- Any other better design for the above problem with an example ?
- Can we iterate over concurrentLinkedQueue with multiple threads and delete the elements while iterating ?

> Memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent collections,
>   actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a
>   ConcurrentLinkedQueue happen-before actions subsequent to the access
>   or removal of that element from the ConcurrentLinkedQueue in another
>   thread.

Comment: I would look at [blocking queues](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), because your consumer threads may have to deal with the situation when they 'outwork' the producer(s). And then you can stop the threads via sending some special item to them (4 copies, so each thread will consume one)

Comment: @tevemadar thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should not iterate but create 4 thread each polling data from the queue so that polled data will be deleted or in other words consumed

```
// your queue
ConcurrentLinkedQueue concurrentLinkedQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();

    // create 4 Threads
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (!concurrentLinkedQueue.isEmpty()) {
                // consume element
                var element = concurrentLinkedQueue.poll();

                // do something with element
                // here
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: why not `while (!concurrentLinkedQueue.isEmpty())`?

Comment: @LeiYang, nice suggestion. The one is better

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `offer` and `poll` methods on a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, rather than directly using an iterator. The iterator is [weakly consistent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#iterator--).

```
while(true) {
  final Item item = queue.poll();
  if (item == null) {
    break;
  }
  // do something with item
}
```

It is safe for many threads to call `offer` and/or `poll` concurrently.